# Connect-mongo Update Results In Constant Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Store' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I upgraded the connect-mongo npm today and my application keeps crashing due to this error.  Can anyone advise a way to fix this?

**The Error:**

```
/Users/ac360/Desktop/node/application/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:30
  var Store = connect.session.Store;
                             ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Store' of undefined
```

**Here's How I Set Up Connect-Mongo**

```
//express/mongo session storage
        app.use(express.session({
            secret: 'MEAN',
            store: new mongoStore({
                url: config.db,
                collection: 'sessions'
            })
        }));
```

Answer (score 2):

After hours of searching, this worked for me:
https://github.com/mrzepinski/connect-mongo/commit/21359889c4c5b81db85183a7e0549500160cedf2

With:

```
"connect-mongo": "^0.4.0",
"express": "^4.1.0",
"express-session": "^1.0.2",
"mongoose": "^3.8.8"
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! You might want to add the code change to your answer in case the commit is deleted or the link goes dead for some reason.

Comment: "You might want to add the code change to your answer in case the commit is deleted or the link goes dead for some reason."


Like it has :(